# I have no errors in the apache log for deploying django, but my page doesn't load

Tags: django, apache

Good morning everyone, I am deploying a django application on Apache and at the moment there are no errors in the LOG after I add the root folder after the first slash in the WSGIScriptAlias line

```
/projeto_cad_usuarios C:/Apache24/htdocs/Cadastro/ project_cad_users/project_cad_users/wsgi.py
```

But in the browser it does not load my application, it only shows the folders and files of the project. Below is the log:

```
[Tue Jul 04 10:31:25.317454 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5672:tid 520] AH00455: Apache/2.4.57 (Win64) mod_wsgi/4.9.5.dev1 Python/3.11 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jul 04 10:31:25.318481 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5672:tid 520] AH00456: Apache Lounge VS17 Server built: May 31 2023 10:48:22 
[Tue Jul 04 10:31:25.318481 2023] [core:notice] [pid 5672:tid 520] AH00094: Command line: 'httpd -d C:/Apache24' 
[Tue Jul 04 10:31:25.320473 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5672:tid 520] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 3856 
[Tue Jul 04 10:31:25.727677 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 3856:tid 564] mod_wsgi (pid=3856): Initializing Python. 
[Tue Jul 04 10:31:25.740643 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 3856:tid 564] mod_wsgi (pid=3856): Attach interpreter ''. 
[Tue Jul 04 10:31:25.748622 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 3856:tid 564] mod_wsgi (pid=3856): Adding 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/Cadastro/env/Lib/site-packages' to path. 
[Tue Jul 04 10:31:25.765605 2023] [wsgi:info] [pid 3856:tid 564] mod_wsgi (pid=3856): Imported 'mod_wsgi'. 
[Tue Jul 04 10:31:25.768597 2023] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 3856:tid 564] AH00354: Child: Starting 64 worker threads.
```

**My file httpd.conf**

```
Alias /robots.txt "C:/Apache24/htdocs/Cadastro/projeto_cad_usuarios/static/robots.txt"
Alias /favicon.ico "C:/Apache24/htdocs/Cadastro/projeto_cad_usuarios/static/favicon.ico"

Alias /media/ "C:/Apache24/htdocs/Cadastro/projeto_cad_usuarios/media/media"
Alias /static/ "C:/Apache24/htdocs/Cadastro/projeto_cad_usuarios/static"

<Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/Cadastro/projeto_cad_usuarios/static">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/Cadastro/projeto_cad_usuarios/media/media">
    Require all granted
</Directory>

LoadFile "C:/Python311/python311.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "C:/Apache24/htdocs/Cadastro/env/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi-4.9.5.dev1-py3.11-win-amd64.egg/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp311-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "C:/Apache24/htdocs/Cadastro/env"
WSGIScriptAlias /projeto_cad_usuarios "C:/Apache24/htdocs/Cadastro/projeto_cad_usuarios/projeto_cad_usuarios/wsgi.py"

<Directory "C:/Apache24/htdocs/Cadastro/projeto_cad_usuarios/projeto_cad_usuarios">
<Files wsgi.py>
    Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

**WSGI.py**

```
import os
import sys

print(sys.path)

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'projeto_cad_usuarios.settings')
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Windows Server 2019
Python 3.11
Apache 2.4

I've been trying to get a django application into production for two weeks.
I was using Apache from xampp and I switched to ApacheLounge, but as in xampp it presented errors in the LOG and in the browser.
I faced several problems before to install mod_wsgi without errors.
Finally, I was doing tests on the httpd.conf file and added the root folder in the line WSGIScriptAlias /projeto_cad_usuarios "C:/Apache24/htdocs/Cadastro/projeto_cad_usuarios/projeto_cad_usuarios/wsgi.py" resulting in Apache loading without errors but without rendering the django application page.